# ¿como puedo recuperar un dato obtenido de la interfas?

Tags: python, tkinter

resulta que hice un scrip para descargar los post de un perfil de instagram con python y pues le quise agregar una interfas grafica con tkinter(no es de mi mejores interfases ) y a la hora de recuperar la informacion de la variable n1(nomre de usuario) me tira error.

````
from tkinter import *
import instaloader

parser = instaloader.Instaloader()

def insta():
    n1.get()
    parser.download_profile(n1, profile_pic=True)

root = Tk()
root.config(bd=10)

n1 = StringVar()

Label(root, text="INSTALOADER").pack()
Label(root, text="Descargar las publicaciones,").pack()
Label(root, text="de un perfil de instagram").pack()
Label(root, text=" ").pack()
Label(root, text="Dijite la cuenta de usuario").pack()
Entry(root, justify="center", textvariable=n1).pack()# Numero1
Label(root, text=" ").pack()
Button(root, text="Insertar", command=insta).pack()
root.mainloop()```
````

Answer (score 0):

Es porque estás pasando el StringVar directo cuando debes pasarle el valor del campo.

```py
def insta():
    parser.download_profile(n1.get(), profile_pic=True)
```